# Session variable is null when accessed second time

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am new to this forum. I am designing a JSP-Servlet application and using session variables to store objects.
Problem is, when I access the session variables for second time it returns null.
Here is the flow of my app -

I have a jsp page with mulitple link buttons. When user clicks on any button a servlet is called with respective parameters. eg 1 is passed if button1 is clicked, 2 if button2 is clicked,etc.

Servlet gets an arraylist from session variable which is already created earlier and depending on requested parameter gets the data from arraylist, processes it and sends response to another jsp say jsp2.

jsp2 also has similar link buttons and should do the same task. When the same Servlet is called from jsp2 or even if the page is refreshed, the session variable is null this time.

In my web.xml file under the session-config tag I have set the timeout to -1 so that session never expires.

```
<session-config>
      <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout> 
   </session-config>
```

In the servlet I get the session variable as-

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list = (ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("mylist");
```

When the servlet is called second time or even if the page is refreshed the list is null.
I put few lines to check if session is valid-and it prints the second time.

```
if(!request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
 System.out.println("Session is Expired !!");
}
```

and the `session.getAttribute("mylist")` returns `NullPointerException`.

I am sure that I have not used `session.invalidate()` anywhere by chance to end the session.
I dont understand what is going wrong..can someone can explain me ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending the response to some other jsp page and see if you are able to access session variable from there. If yes then there is problem in your current jsp.
Certainly the session is getting expired somewhere for sure otherwise request.getSession() will definitely return the previously created session.

Comment: You are right dude..I am able to access the session variable from other jsp's and the session was actually getting destroyed in the index.jsp included in my previous jsp page. Many thanks to you !

Answer (score 2):

You would need to try with `getSession(true)` for the first time  or `getSession()`.
False argument will not return session if the session doesn't exist. Only for the first time you would need to supply true in to the `getSession` call.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

According to servlet specification,

> **HttpSession getSession(boolean create)**
>
> Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no 
>   current session and create is true, returns a new
>   session.
>
> If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method 
>   returns null.
>
> To make sure the session is properly maintained, you must call this method before the response is committed. If the container is
>   using cookies to maintain session integrity and is asked to create a
>   new session when the response is committed, an IllegalStateException
>   is thrown.

**Edit - Session from session id**

```
 HttpSessionContext sc=request.getSession().getSessionContext();
    HttpSession session=sc.getSession(session_id);
```

Note- This method is deprecated now due to security reason.

Comment: But why is it not able to get my previous session ? Is there a way for a request to refer to a particular session using its session id ?

Comment: What do you meant by particular session?  If you had a previous session( and/or only if you had created a session previously) , you should get it with getSession(false). But how do know if its the first time or second time?

Comment: In my case request.getSession(false) is not returning the previously created session if the Servlet is called second time..if I use request.getSession(true) it is creating a new session. I figured it out with the sessionId..so i meant to say if I know the sessionId of previously created session how can I obtain it gain using sessionId ?

Comment: There was an option to find a session using sessionid till servlet 2.2. This method is been deprecated due to security reason. By the way, if you have session( if its not expired), you should be getting with getSession(). If you are getting null value, that means session is expired.

Answer (score 0):

Set timeout to `0`, not `-1` if you want unlimited session time.

Comment: Could you explain more, the attribute is null or session object?

Comment: The session.getAttribute("mylist") returns NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the attribute somewhere, before you can retrieve it:

```
session.setAttribute("mylist", list);
```

Comment: My problem is the list(session variable) is null when it is accessed second time. The list is already set somewhere before I am retrieving it.

Comment: Well, that's not surprising, when `list` is null.

Comment: That's because of you stored null value in session's attribute. Show us piece of code where are you adding this attribute.

Comment: I am sorry the session.getAttribute("mylist") returns NullPointerException

Comment: Where are you creating session? request.getSession(false) won't do it.

Comment: Session is created on a different servlet say Servlet1 and is retrieved in another Servlet say Servlet2. I passed false in it because I dont want to create a new session if not exists.